# Safari javascript Set Iterator get values

Tags: javascript, safari, ecmascript-6

The mozilla documentation says that Safari supports the Set Iterator next() method, but when I call it from the Safari console I get the following error:

```
 var adj = new Set();
 adj.add('val1');
 adj.add('val2');
 adj.values().next();
 TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'adj.values().next()')
```

adj being my Set of adjacent nodes. In Chrome and Firefox this works just fine. Im using version 7.1 of Safari, which is [supposed to support this functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/values).

I realize that Sets are new to javascript, but its the exact data structure I need for what Im trying to do. Is there a better way to iterate over the values of a Set? Or should I just implement my own Set and make it work across all the browsers?

Thanks in advance for any pointers you can give me!

Comment: You could use `adj.forEach(...)`.

Comment: You are right. In my case since I really only want one item, I should be able to do `adj.forEach( ...work..; return;);`